# "FetchError no backend connection" error when Apache is running

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, centos, varnish

```
[centos@ip-172-35-25-65 ~]$  varnishlog
    0 CLI          - Rd ping
    0 CLI          - Wr 200 19 PONG 1635280998 1.0
    0 CLI          - Rd ping
    0 CLI          - Wr 200 19 PONG 1635281001 1.0
   10 SessionOpen  c 127.0.0.2 55870 127.0.0.2:80
   10 ReqStart     c 127.0.0.2 55870 894208400
   10 RxRequest    c GET
   10 RxURL        c /
   10 RxProtocol   c HTTP/1.0
   10 RxHeader     c X-Real-IP: 198.95.75.75
   10 RxHeader     c X-Forwarded-For: 198.95.75.75
   10 RxHeader     c X-Forwarded-Proto: https
   10 RxHeader     c X-Forwarded-Port: 80
   10 RxHeader     c Host: staging03.cherry.com
   10 RxHeader     c Connection: close
   10 RxHeader     c Cache-Control: max-age=0
   10 RxHeader     c Authorization: Basic aGc6am9objEyMw==
   10 RxHeader     c Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
   10 RxHeader     c User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/95.0.4638.54 Safari/537.36
   10 RxHeader     c Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
   10 RxHeader     c Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
   10 RxHeader     c Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,fr;q=0.8
   10 RxHeader     c Cookie: ajs_anonymous_id=%22424f4cd9-cbbc-4ead-83b1-273cb21cf453%22; _fbp=fb.1.1630002144579.2012566540; __qca=P0-1416512434-1630002144589; _edwvts=708154457303700204; _gid=GA1.2.1572498662.1635275261; ajs_user_id=%224543534%40mimpi99.com%22; _gcl_au=1.1.
   10 VCL_call     c recv pass
   10 VCL_call     c hash
   10 Hash         c /
   10 Hash         c staging03.cherry.com
   10 Hash         c 80
   10 Hash         c ajs_anonymous_id=%22424f4cd9-cbbc-4ead-83b1-273cb21cf453%22; _fbp=fb.1.1630002144579.2012566540; __qca=P0-1416512434-1630002144589; _edwvts=708154457303700204; _gid=GA1.2.1572498662.1635275261; ajs_user_id=%224543534%40mimpi99.com%22; _gcl_au=1.1.1880042
   10 VCL_return   c hash
   10 VCL_call     c pass pass
   10 FetchError   c no backend connection
   10 VCL_call     c error deliver
   10 VCL_call     c deliver deliver
   10 TxProtocol   c HTTP/1.1
   10 TxStatus     c 503
   10 TxResponse   c Service Unavailable
   10 TxHeader     c Server: Varnish
   10 TxHeader     c Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
   10 TxHeader     c Retry-After: 5
   10 TxHeader     c Content-Length: 392
   10 TxHeader     c Accept-Ranges: bytes
   10 TxHeader     c Date: Tue, 26 Oct 2021 20:43:23 GMT
   10 TxHeader     c X-Varnish: 894208400
   10 TxHeader     c Via: 1.1 varnish
   10 TxHeader     c Connection: close
   10 TxHeader     c X-Age: 0
   10 TxHeader     c X-Cache: MISS
   10 Length       c 392
   10 ReqEnd       c 894208400 1635281003.852778196 1635281003.852984428 0.000073195 0.000165701 0.000040531
   10 SessionClose c error
   10 StatSess     c 127.0.0.2 55870 0 1 1 0 1 0 273 392
    0 CLI          - Rd ping
    0 CLI          - Wr 200 19 PONG 1635281004 1.0
    0 CLI          - Rd ping
    0 CLI          - Wr 200 19 PONG 1635281007 1.0
    0 CLI          - Rd ping
    0 CLI          - Wr 200 19 PONG 1635281010 1.0
    0 CLI          - Rd ping
    0 CLI          - Wr 200 19 PONG 1635281013 1.0
```

I tried to log what was happening when I got from the client side:

```
Error 503 Service Unavailable
Service Unavailable

Guru Meditation:
XID: 894208400
```

Now, I thought it was because of Apache not running, because when I close varnish I get a 502 gateway error from nginx. Anyway, I read the error logs:

```
[Tue Oct 26 14:53:47 2021] [notice] SELinux policy enabled; httpd running as context unconfined_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
[Tue Oct 26 14:53:47 2021] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Tue Oct 26 14:53:47 2021] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Tue Oct 26 14:53:47 2021] [notice] Digest: done
[Tue Oct 26 14:53:47 2021] [notice] FastCGI: process manager initialized (pid 23090)
[Tue Oct 26 14:53:47 2021] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_fastcgi/2.4.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Oct 26 14:53:52 2021] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /var/www/html/
[Tue Oct 26 14:53:52 2021] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /var/www/html/favicon.ico, referer: http://staging03.hgreg.com/
[Tue Oct 26 15:01:21 2021] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /var/www/html/
[Tue Oct 26 15:01:42 2021] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue Oct 26 15:01:42 2021] [notice] SELinux policy enabled; httpd running as context unconfined_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
[Tue Oct 26 15:01:42 2021] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Tue Oct 26 15:01:42 2021] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Tue Oct 26 15:01:42 2021] [notice] Digest: done
[Tue Oct 26 15:01:42 2021] [notice] FastCGI: process manager initialized (pid 23299)
[Tue Oct 26 15:01:42 2021] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_fastcgi/2.4.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Oct 26 15:11:56 2021] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
```

I saw SIGTERM, shutting down, so I thought maybe I should restart Apache and I did, but I get the same error, and no new logs in the error_log.

```
[centos@ip-172-35-25-65 ~]$ sudo service httpd restart
Stopping httpd:                                            [  OK  ]
Starting httpd:                                            [  OK  ]
[centos@ip-172-35-25-65 ~]$ date
Tue Oct 26 17:12:32 EDT 2021
[centos@ip-172-35-25-65 ~]$
```

Now, I run a puppet config, but it didn't completely run, but I have the same files. So I am wondering what might be the issue. One of the Apache config file which is loaded since all files with conf are loaded is like this:

```
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName preprod.staging03.cherry.com

    
    
    ServerAlias betacherry.staging03.cherry.com staging03.cherry.com
    
    

    DocumentRoot /home/staging03/version/preprod.staging03.cherry.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@cherry.ca

    SetEnv environment preprod
    SetEnv project staging03

    UseCanonicalName Off
    #CustomLog /var/log/httpd/preprod.staging03.cherry.com_log combined
    #CustomLog /var/log/httpd/preprod.staging03.cherry.com-bytes_log "%{%s}t %I .\n%{%s}t %O ."

    ## User cherry # Needed for Cpanel::ApacheConf
    UserDir disabled
    UserDir enabled staging03
    
      #<IfModule mod_suphp.c>
    #    suPHP_UserGroup staging03 staging03
    #</IfModule>
    
    SuexecUserGroup staging03 staging03
    
    <directory "/home/staging03/version">
        AddHandler php5-fcgi .php
        Action php5-fcgi /php5-fcgi-staging03
        AllowOverride All

        
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "staging03-preprod"
        AuthUserFile "/etc/httpd/conf.d/htpasswd.staging03"
        require valid-user

        satisfy any
        deny from all

        Order deny,allow
        SetEnvIf X-Hg-Internal-IP 1 HgInternalIP=1
        Allow from env=HgInternalIP

        SetEnvIf User-Agent "Amazon CloudFront" AmazonCloudFront
        Allow from env=AmazonCloudFront

        SetEnvIf User-Agent "^(.*)Lighthouse(.*)$" Lighthouse=1
        Allow from env=Lighthouse
        
    </directory>
    <IfModule concurrent_php.c>
        php5_admin_value open_basedir "/home/staging03:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php:/tmp"
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule !concurrent_php.c>
        <IfModule mod_php5.c>
            php_admin_value open_basedir "/home/staging03:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php:/tmp"
        </IfModule>
        <IfModule sapi_apache2.c>
            php_admin_value open_basedir "/home/staging03:/usr/lib/php:/usr/php4/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php:/usr/local/php4/lib/php:/tmp"
        </IfModule>
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule !mod_disable_suexec.c>
        <IfModule !mod_ruid2.c>
            SuexecUserGroup staging03 staging03
        </IfModule>
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_ruid2.c>
        RMode config
        RUidGid staging03 staging03
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule itk.c>
        # For more information on MPM ITK, please read:
        #   http://mpm-itk.sesse.net/
        AssignUserID staging03 staging03
    </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

So what files should I look at and how do I check it's not Apache that's the problem, because we have nginx routing to varnish and then routing to Apache, so I am thinking Apache is the problem, but I don't get any useful info from the log and Apache runs without any issue, it's just not servicing the page and Varnish can't reach Apache for some reason?

I am running CENTOS 6, and I have another server with the same configurations that's running well, but when I diff the etc folder, I don't really see any significant difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your logs I can see that Both Varnish & Apache are running on the same machine. Varnish should run on port `80` and Apache on port `8080`.

Apparently there also an Nginx running, so I'm assuming that's for TLS termination, running on port `443`.

### Step 1: ensure Apache is successfully listening on port 8080

Run `sudo netstat -plnt` to figure out which ports are used by each service.

Ensure that the `httpd` service is listening on port `8080` and verify this by running `curl -I localhost:8080`.

### Step 2: add a health probe for the backend in your VCL file

The standard VCL doesn't offer a health probe for your default backend. Using the VCL code below, you can constantly monitor the backend health:

```
backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8080";
    .probe = {
        .url = "/";
        .timeout = 2s;
        .interval = 5s;
        .window = 10;
        .threshold = 5;
   }
}
```

Once the probe is added and the new VCL is loaded, you can call the following command to check the health of the backend, based on the probe:

```
varnishlog -g raw -i backend_health
```

If the output contains `Still sick`, you know that backend is not available and the status code may tell you why that is.

### Step 3: upgrade your Varnish server

I couldn't help but notice terms like `RxHeader` in your VSL output. This is a clear hint that you're using an ancient version of Varnish that is no longer supported.

Even in really old versions of Varnish, the `RxHeader` was replaced with `ReqHeader`.

> My advice: upgrade to **Varnish 6.0 LTS**. This LTS version of Varnish comes with frequent bug fixes and security patches. See https://www.varnish-software.com/developers/tutorials/installing-varnish-centos/ to learn how to install this version on CentOS.